# how to distinguish between a method and an attribute in python by name

Tags: python

Sometimes, I find it hard to distinguish between a method and an attribute by it's name without appending parentheses.

For example:
there're `keys()` method and `text` attribute in `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` class.

`text`:The text attribute can be used to hold additional data associated with the element.

`keys()`:Returns the elements attribute names as a list.

---

Is there some basic rules/conventions to make `text` an attribute, but `keys()` a method?

If I make `text()` a method, and `keys` an attribute. It still seems OK.

Comment: I believe that it is ok if you will create your object with text as function and keys as attribute. If you need to detect on-fly whether name is a function or var you can use callable, type and isintance methods. You can try to read more about these methods here: http://diveintopython.org/power_of_introspection/built_in_functions.html

Comment: "Is there some basic rules/conventions"?  Yes.  The documentation which you quoted provides the information you want.  What more do you need that what you already found?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only real distinction is that one is callable and one is not, so you can use the builtin function [`callable()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#callable) with the actual object (not a string with the name of it) to determine whether or not it is callable.

In your case:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> elt = ElementTree.Element("")
>>> callable(elt.keys)
True
>>> callable(elt.text)
False
```

Comment: Maybe I interpreted the question differently, but what I thought kev was asking was, since noarg methods and attributes basically do the same thing, how do you remember which one you wrote it as? Because you can't mix the calling syntax.

Comment: @Owen. I must remember which is which to write program. I often mix them up until an Error raised. It's painful.

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem (though in Scala). I don't know a good solution.

Comment: If you has only the name as a string, just use `getattr(obj, name_str)` to obtain the actual attrbiute/method.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about naming conventions, then in Python both are normally lowercase.

If you're talking about how to tell the two apart,

```
from collections import Callable, Container
if isinstance(attribute, Callable):
    return attribute()
elif isinstance(attribute, str):
    return attribute
elif isinstance(attribute, Container):
    return 'Yes' if 'Blah' in attribute
else:
    return str(attribute)
```

is how you check if a variable is pointed at a specific type of object